# Cannot Format Read Only ISO 9660 Bootable USB

Tags: linux, usb, filesystems

I had create a bootable usb drive for my another laptop using Startup Disk Creator and successfully setup ubuntu on that laptop. But when I try to format my usb.

[**I didn't find any format option**.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mS2JO.png)

[Then I try with `mkfs` and noticed it's a read only file system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEqGV.png)

[I try to turn off disk device`s write protect by using `hdparm`. But nothing changed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxt0x.png)

After a long research I have successfully turn off the read only option by [this answer.](https://askubuntu.com/a/1088434/662055)

[`modprobe`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTH47.png)

[`mkfs` run withoun any error. But disk was not formatted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HfAw.png)

[Although Format Disk option there. But,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5vDF.png)

[I got error `udisks-error-quark, 0`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sG3G.png)

[At last trying with `dd` command got I/O error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xITLR.png)

Comment: try creating new partition table using gparted !!!

Comment: gparted also showing Input/Output error on Partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me. Sites like this:

https://linuxiac.com/how-to-create-bootable-usb-drive-using-dd-command/

say to simply use Disk Destroyer to copy the iso and boom. I think I have done it in the past, but now it broke my drive.

I do not think it is bad hardware because it was working great until I used DD to copy an ubuntu iso, and then I couldn't get rid of the iso 9660. Somewhere in this process I did manage to wipe the parition and fs sectors to zeros (checked with `xxd | head -32`), but then it came back somehow when I opened gparted and complained that my physical block size is 2048 bytes but linux thinks is 512 b (same as logical block size).

Your question sums up all the processes I have tried over the past few days nicely, I may add a few more obscure `hdparm` commands: (**extremely dangerous** to your contents, but if you've made it this far its probably nearly a brick anyway). After trying to get write access with `hdparm -r0`, or the `modprobe` unload/reload with quark described in your question:

restore factory settings:

`hdparm --yes-i-know-what-i-am-doing --dco-restore /dev/sdc`

`hdparm --set-sector-size 2048 /dev/sdc`

if your sector sizes also got messed up going through above procedure. Gparted will complain 'physical sector size is x but linux reports it is y' or something to that effect.

I think the next step (if you must not just throw away and get a new drive) is to use vendor specific tools. Have a look at this tree of links:

http://reboot.pro/index.php?showtopic=20865

> https://www.usbdev.ru/

> https://www.usbdev.ru/articles/detect_controller/

> https://www.usbdev.ru/articles/thestart/

> > https://flashboot.ru/files/file/419/

Brush up on your русский, they are windows-only utilities, probably written by Russians in C++. They have compiled a huge database of thumb drive and chip manufacturers, and it explains how it all works with funny translations. Their intentions seem good, but I might distance sensitive data or machines from your academic test machine you load with random privileged binary blobs from God knows where to fix your $12 drive.